# Task_Dispose_NotCompleted error but i don't know why

Tags: c#, task, using-statement

today i was faced with a very strange error regarding Tasks. In my code i tried to use the `using` statement this way:

```cs
protected MyClass() {
    using(var initTask = new Task(() => Init())) {
        initTask.ContinueWith(result => InitCompletedCallBack(result));
        initTask.Start();
    }
}

protected virtual void Init() {}

private void InitCompletedCallBack(AsyncResult result) {
    // Stuff
}
```

When i execute this code i get an Task_Dispose_NotComplete error. The error occures when InitCompletedCallBack has finished.

While trying arounf i changed the using to this:

```cs
using(var initTask = new Task(() => Init())) {
    initTask.ContinueWith(result => InitCompletedCallBack(result));
    initTask.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

And that worked. However, this piece of code will be executed several times when the application starts and thus freezes the application for approximatelly 15-20 seconds. But it shows that something (inside the task?) needs at least one second to finish.

Any ideas what causes this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
When i set the time to wait to 100ms, the error occures. The first lines of the StackTrace are:

```
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose()
bei MyClass..ctor() in c:\Path\to\source\MyClass.cs:line 33.
```

Line 33 is the closing bracket of the using block.

Comment: You should not be disposing tasks anyway and also not using the Task constructor. Use Task.Run. Then, this issue just goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas what causes this behavior?

Your code causes this behavior. You dispose a task that is not yet done. Why do you want to dispose it where you dispose it? Does the using-block make sense where you put it?

Do not dispose a task that you still rely on. Remove the using block.

Comment: Yes, i've removed the using block and this works. But i was interessted in why using the using block causes the error. I do not call the Dispose() method of initTask.

Comment: Because the task is still running. The using block will dispose the task immediately, while your task is supposed to still run. That won't work. You cannot dispose a task *and* expect it to run in the background. Chose one.

Comment: "I do not call the Dispose() method of initTask", When Using() block is end it automatically call dispose() for you. that's the whole idea of Using()!